# Should site search be automatically switched to google?

Tags: discussion, searching

Disclaimer: I have seen [Best way to search AskUbuntu](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/532/best-way-to-search-askubuntu), and even upvoted it, but still... I find that the search box on the main page (and live duplicate search) is quite sloppy by default.

I can explain myself better with an example. I am **sure** this is a duplicate (at least): 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/436371/i-need-to-dual-boot-windows-8-and-ubuntu-13-10-and-am-not-a-techie, so I go to vote for closing as such.

The proposed duplicate lists are really not spot on; even searching with the search box "windows 8 ubuntu alongside" gives a list that is far from the most relevant/voted/whatever: https://askubuntu.com/search?tab=votes&q=%20windows%208%20ubuntu%20alongside --- the most voted result is at 10 votes, I am SURE there is a better one...

The second spot on a google "site:askubuntu.com  windows 8 ubuntu alongside" gives **the** question: [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported) (and the first one is a duplicate to the right one).

So my question is: shouldn't the google.com "site:askubuntu.com..." be the default search method? Maybe this could help with the swamping number of duplicate black screen question over there?

Comment: There's no way SE is going to change this (I kinda like their search, although it is certainly terrible when in the close dialog). I think someone wrote a userscript that could change this however. You can also use `score:10` or `20` or `100` to help filter the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

this is too large to add as a comment but here goes.

I kinda like the *sloppiness* of the search box.
I personally don't like it when a certain website thinks that the Google search results are the ones that I expect.

When I want the searches to be from Google, I would use Google by adding `site:<url>` to my query. What I expect from the search of a certain website is a *filtering* functionality.
[Stuff like these](https://askubuntu.com/help/searching) cannot be done using Google. They have to be done in the site's own search functionality.

```
exact  "words here"
author user:1234
       user:me (yours)
score  score:3 (3+)
       score:0 (none)
...
```

Other than filtering, sorting options can be quite important sometimes, using Google would remove that functionality altogether. *Like sorting by Votes, active, etc.*

*In the earlier days, don't remember the layout or how it was actually shown, there used to be a text which shows tips on how to use the query you used in your search in other search engines like Google.*